Barcelona Airport (BCN), train/bus to Sitges?
Is there a train (or bus, if no train) from Barcelona Airport (BCN) direct to Sitges?  I am looking on the Rodalies Train/Transport website and there are multiple stations in Barcelona to choose, but I don't believe any of them are actually at BCN.
Flying in to BCN, would one need to go into the main city, then get a train?  Or are there direct train/buses from BCN to Sitges?
Related - when/if a train is found, should I purchase tickets ahead of time or is it safe to buy day-of "on-site"?
Edit: For quick reference, these are the stations showing in Barcelona:


The airport has two terminals: Terminal 1 has a connection to the metro (and buses), while Terminal 2 has both metro and local train (Rodalies) connections. Both the metro and the Rodalies train are at the end of the line, and both go through El Prat de Llobregat station on their way to Barcelona. A map is available on the Rodalies website (the airport is in the bottom left, and Sitges is up and to the left).
If you're arriving into Terminal 2 (mostly low-cost carriers), then the easiest way by train is to take the Rodalies train one stop to El Prat de Llobregat and change there to a train towards Vilanova which will take you to Sitges. You will need to change to the other platform for this as you'll be kind of "doubling back" on yourself (but a ticket will be valid. A single ticket for this route would be a Rodalies zone 1-4 ticket and would cost €4.90. Both trains run every 30 minutes, and the journey in total is timetabled to take around 44 minutes including the 10 minute change at El Prat. All trains from the Airport station stop at El Prat de Llobregat, but from El Prat make sure you get a train going to Vilanova (it will say R2 VILANOVA on the front and side), as some trains on weekdays stop short at Castelldefels (if you do happen to get one of these, you can just change at Castelldefels but you will need to change platform).
From Terminal 1, you'd need to either take the free shuttle bus from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 and then as above, or alternatively take the metro line L9 to El Prat de Llobregat station and then the Rodalies train as above. There is a supplement on the metro for journeys to and from the airport, and you would need two tickets for this journey (one for the metro and one for the Rodalies train) for a total of €10.40 (€5.50 metro and €4.90 Rodalies). Using the metro, this journey would take around 12 minutes for the metro and 27 for the train, plus waiting and changing times - so roughly around 10 minutes longer than the Rodalies train from T2. The shuttle bus from Terminal 1 to Terminal 2 also takes around 10 minutes, so the times are comparable.
For these trains you can only buy tickets on the day. There are options for multiple journeys - for example if there are two of you and you are planning a day trip from Sitges into Barcelona then you could get a Bonotren which is 10 journeys for €31.45 (valid only on the Rodalies trains) - but in any case you can buy the ticket just before you travel. To complicate matters there are two separate fare scales for multi-journey tickets depending on whether they are valid only on Rodalies trains or also on buses/metro/etc, but for single tickets none of this applies and the pricing structure is "simpler".
For completeness, there is also a bus service from Barcelona Airport to Sitges which runs one bus an hour and takes around 45 minutes.
If you do take the train, for the journey from El Prat to Sitges try to sit on the left hand side of the train (facing direction of travel) as between Castelldefels and Sitges the line runs through a set of tunnels cut into the cliffs and the views are pretty scenic.

Thanks very much for this!  So it seems like it will be no problem to wait and buy tickets the day-of (even required), for BCN-Sitges, and the return?

Excellent detailed answer (+1) but it would probably be even better if you could add how long it takes (especially for comparison with the bus option).

@BruceWayne You'll have no problem at all buying tickets on the day (the fares don't change and there is no "quota" for tickets, so they can't sell out). One thing to be aware of is that if you're planning on travelling on a weekend between now andn 26 May 2024, there are works on the line between Castelldefels and Sitges and you'd need make a further change as all trains from El Prat will stop short of Sitges.

The station name in the form for BCN aiport is Aeroport and is served by R2 Nord line train

Stiges is located on another branch of the R2, R2 Sud
You can change in El Prat de Llogberat from a R2 Nord line train

The planner forcasts 45min trip time (including change) and a fare of 4.5€

Aha! If I book at Aeroport, would that effectively be the El Prat de Llogberat station? I tried doing Aeroport to Sitges for a date in May, but the site says "Timetable not available. Please go to Service updates."  Edit: Tried same but from origin El Prat de Llobregat and it says timetable not available.
